# Should a Windows based build server get automatic updates installed?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, jenkins, build, server

I'm asking myself if it is a common practice to have automatic updates activated on build server with windows operating system. The build server uses jenkins, visual studio and java to drive the build. On the one hand I want a system that is clearly defined which software is installed. On the other I have a server that should have up to date patches installed.

What is a common practice?

Answer (score 0):

In my previous company, we were using Windows to host the Jenkins master and all the slaves. We were building our code with Visual Studio 2010. We tested the automatic updates and it broke our configuration 2 times (in 3 years). So if you want to control your server's configuration, I recommend to apply the Microsoft patches manually (you can test the patches on a staging environment before applying the patch in production).

Comment: Hi Bruno. I'm not the c++ expert, but is it possible that all generated libraries get the assembly identity of the updated visual studio? Something like that: "<assemblyIdentity type='win32' name='Microsoft.VC80.CRT' version='8.0.50727.6195' "

Comment: Than it maybe is not compatible with a distributed redistributable. Or is my understanding to low?

Comment: I'm not a C++ expert too (just a release engineer) :) So I cannot answer to your question about the generated libs. Maybe you can add some tags on your post if you want to reach C++/Microsoft expert.